# IE6 float sidepanel bug

Tags: html, xhtml, internet-explorer-6

Im trying to fix a bug that only appears in internet explorer 6.

The problem is that the side panel moved below the footer of the page in Ie6.

Can anybody help?

http://www.perfectclaims.com/houses4cash/ie6.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is problem from `<table>` tags

You can delete "width" from last 2 tables

width="600"

and

width="731"

You can just delet this width from `<table>` tag

Comment: Do you know of a way that I can strech the bottom bar across the page without causing the side panel to go back below the page?

Comment: Yes, you have to put bottom bart after <div id="content"> some textt </div>,


<div id="content">

bla bla bla
</div>
<div id="footer">footer contet</div>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but try putting this below the sidebar:

```
<div class='clear'></div>
```

And use the following style for `.clear`:

```
.clear{clear:both}
```

**Edit:** The current clearing `<div>` you have needs to be inside the `</div>` you have just before it, I think.